# .htaccess - Limit access to files unless accessed by server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403

I'm looking for help with .htaccess rewrite rules for my server.

Considering I have the following structure:

```
index.html
foo.html
private\
        bar.js
        secret.txt
public\
       helloworld.js
       cat.jpg
```

I need the following conditions:

1. Users navigating to `http://example.com`, `http://example.com/index.html`, `http://example.com/foo.html` or `http://example.com/foo` should be able to load up without issue.
2. Users navigating to `http://example.com/private/bar.js` or `http://example.com/private/secret.txt` and any other file in this folder should get a 403 forbidden, although these files should be able to be accessed by the html files which use it.
3. Users navigating to `http://example.com/public/` should be able to access anything in there.

The last point is just for me to understand how I could negate the rule if needed. I managed to get somewhere by blocking files unless they were .html but it didn't work for when the extension was omitted and it was very messy so I'm hoping some pros could help me out with a clean way of doing this.

EDIT: Clarified requirement #2 to include all files in the private folder

Comment: Can you add an example on how do you think the secret files will be used by the html?

Comment: In case of say the javascript file, it could be used by html so I assume it would need to be limited by referer much like hotlinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Basically its for 2nd condition. Your 3rd condition anyways doesn't needs any rule(considering that you don't have any other rules for public folder as per 3rd condition).

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^private/(bar\.js|secret\.txt)/?$ - [R=403,L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Make sure either you use above OR following rules only at a time, following considers that you want to allow only `http://example.com, index.html, foo.html OR foo` URLs as per your first condition and block others if this is the case then one could try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##In case you want to forbid anything apart from:
##http://example.com, index.html, foo.html OR foo then following.
RewriteCond ^(index\.html|foo\.html|foo)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]

##For forbidding private/bar.js and private/secret.txt here.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^private/(bar\.js|secret\.txt)/?$ - [R=403,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the 2nd solution was what I needed. Could you elaborate what the variable ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS is doing?

Comment: @randonoob, `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` prevents looping by checking an internal mod_rewrite variable REDIRECT_STATUS which is set to 200 after first successful internal redirect.